# Background image stop appearing in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I was doing a work for a client when I got this problem:

The background images stop loading after 26 background image (tried to change images for fakeimg.pl images and I tried to disable the lightbox too).

Any idea what would cause that?

I added a if GET test=stackoverflow  to show the pictures.

Here's the link: http://amenagementscomcept.com/index.php?page=realisations&test=stackoverflow

Edit: Forgot to mention here, the problem is in IE8 and IE9

Edit2: Deleted the picture, re-uploaded it, it's still bugging at the 26th picture

Comment: Umm, what's the problem?

Comment: Looks fine in IE8 on my PC.

Comment: The pictures stop showing after http://amenagementscomcept.com/images/photos/fileMjinLfnfPg.jpg

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 was released on year 2009.  
2013 - 2009 = 4. Just pointing-out.

Comment: @Alec you underestimate how many people hate Windows 7.

Comment: Does reordering the images still cause the same problem at image #26?

Comment: Yes, same problem, same place (different picture)

Comment: How many selectors do you have in your css stylesheet? IE only supports 4095 selectors. I doubt you have that many but could be a reason.

Comment: Start by validating your document.  You have 81 errors, most of which are caused by improper nesting and invalid placement of style tags for your doctype.

Comment: This is a client site, I can't really do much about what he didn't asked for, will validate for my part I guess, thanks.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say that the additional style tags for each image is what's pushing IE over the edge.  For dynamic backgrounds like that, you can just add the style inline to the tag it belongs to:  `<a href="path/to/img.jpg" style="background: url(path/to/img.jpg)">`.  Though realistically, it should be an actual image tag since the image is content here, not a decoration.

Comment: I would do that, but I have to center the image and resize it depending on the proportion and everything so I guess using a background image with background-position and background-size is the most fitting solution

Comment: Inline style is indeed fixing it, could you make an answer so I can accept it please? Thanks to everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer doesn't  support for CMYK JPEG

If you have ImageMagick:

```
identify -verbose image.jpg
```

will show you the image colorspace. If it's CMYK, you can convert to RGB with:

```
convert broken.jpg -colorspace RGB fixed.jpg
```

Or try in Photoshop, Convert your CMYK files to RGB. RGB files are support by IE.

Good Luck !

Comment: It's not this, as you can see, you can still open the lightbox with the picture and see the picture, also I looked all the base files. Thanks for the tip, will keep that in mind for future problems